# Insert value from select within the same table

Tags: mysql, mysql-insert-id

`table:message [id,username,userid,message,type,timediff,timestamp]`

I have a table called message. When a message is started a new row is created, with a timestamp and timediff of null.

When the message is ended I would like to insert that into a row with the difference in time.

Eg Start `1,username,1234,message,start/s,null,000001` End: `2,username,1234,message,end/s,**20**,000021`

```
INSERT into Messages.message (username,userid,message,type,timediff) 
values ("username","1234","Test","Ended/S",(
    select sum(unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())-unix_timestamp(timestamp))
    from messages
        WHERE userid = "1234" 
        AND type = "Started/S"
        Order by timestamp desc
        limit 1))
```

I also get an error, which I can't make sense of
`Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'message' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: This is not nearly enough information and on top of that you haven't actually asked any question here.  For sql questions always provide schema, and example of your expected result, and if you need help with a query, show us what you've tried that *didn't* work so someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable to use the [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) syntax for a query like that. I think something like this should work:

```
insert into message (id, username, userid, message, type, timediff)
select id, username, userid, message, 'Ended/S', unix_timestamp() - unix_timestamp(tstamp)
from message m
where tstamp = (select MAX(tstamp) 
                from message m1 
                where m1.userid=1234 and m1.type='Started/S');
```

I've made a small demo on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc37c2f/1) where you can see it in operation.

Comment: Thanks that "m" was all it took ;-)

Comment: @JamesCoombes if you didn't use this as an answer, you should post what you did use as an answer and accept that instead.